# amsmath package error using SIAM LaTeX template files

Tags: amsmath, ntheorem

I am preparing paper using the latest SIAM template [siamart_0516.zip](https://www.siam.org/journals/tex/standard/siamart_0516.zip) downloaded from http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php.

I am having errors in math equations containing `\tag{}` command with *special* characters (e.g., `\mathbf{}`, `\bar{}` and etc.) in math mode. To be clear, the following code:

```
\documentclass[review]{siamart0516}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{$\bar{x}$}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produce an error:

```
Package amsmath Error: \bar allowed only in math mode. \end{equation}
```

while using only `\tag{$x$}` without `\bar{}` works fine:

```
\documentclass[review]{siamart0516}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{$x$}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Finally, initial *non-working* code using the standard article `documentclass`, i.e., replacing `\documentclass[review]{siamart0516}` with `\documentclass{article}` works like a charm.

Any guesses what is causing this issue and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For very strange reasons, `ntheorem`, when used with the `thmmarks` and `amsmath` options, redefines `\maketag@@@` (an internal command of `amsmath`) to do, among other things

```
\settowidth{\tagwidth}{$##1$}%
```

This is utterly wrong, because `##1` is substituted with the `\tag` text, which is supposed to be in *text* mode.

Now, what happens when you do `\tag{$x$}`? The `\settowidth` macro puts the second argument in an `\hbox`, so what results is `\hbox{$$x$$}` which is legal, because `$$` in restricted horizontal mode just typesets an empty math formula, and what's measured is a text mode “x”. But `$\bar{x}$` (or any other inherently math), the code `\hbox{$$\bar{x}$$}` tries to typeset `\bar{x}` in text mode, and the error is shown. Moreover, something like `\tag{a*}` would end up to be wrongly measured, because the width of `a*` in text mode is quite different from the width of `$a*$`.

Solution: patch the relevant command to remove the nasty `$` characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\patchcmd{\SetTagPlusEndMark}{$}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SetTagPlusEndMark}{$}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{$\bar{x}$}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same works with `siamart0516.cls`:

```
\documentclass[review]{siamart0516}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\SetTagPlusEndMark}{$}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SetTagPlusEndMark}{$}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{$\bar{x}$}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While @Przemysław Scherwentke `\mbox` workaround is the most straightforward, this one is the most comprehensive and answers both part of my question!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a "feature" of `ntheorem` package

You can reproduce the error with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\RequirePackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}%[1.33] (bad use of this argument in siam class)



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{$\bar{x}$}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

could trace exactly where it goes wrong but I'd be tempted to simply accept the other answer and use `\mbox` workaround.

Comment: How could I not to upvote this answer! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If it may be an aswer only for the second part of yor question, putting into `\mbox` seems to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[review]{siamart0516}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{\mbox{$\bar{x}$}}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```