# Erratic position of QED symbol at the end of proof environment using SIAM template

Tags: equations, theorems

I already had issues (described here: [amsmath package error using SIAM LaTeX template files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328946/amsmath-package-error-using-siam-latex-template-files)) with the newest version of SIAM LaTeX template from http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php

For now, I would like to clarify why the position of QED symbol in the **proof** environment depends on the equation environment type. Using example from manual with `\begin{displaymath}\end{displaymath}`:

```
\begin{corollary}
  Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere. If $f(x)$
  has at least two roots, then $f’(x)$ must have at least one root.
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
  Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
  By \cref{thm:mvt}, there exists a number $c$ such that
  \begin{displaymath}
    f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{0-0}{b-a} = 0.
  \end{displaymath}
\end{proof}
```

puts QED symbol at the right position (end of the equation).
[image]

However, using `$$ $$` QED symbol is completely absent from the proof environment:

```
\begin{corollary}
    Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere. If $f(x)$
    has at least two roots, then $f’(x)$ must have at least one root.
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
    Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
    By \cref{thm:mvt}, there exists a number $c$ such that
    $$
    f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{0-0}{b-a} = 0.
    $$
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Finally, using `\begin{equation*}\end{equation*}` puts QED symbol in a wrong position, i.e., above the equation.

```
\begin{corollary}
  Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere. If $f(x)$
  has at least two roots, then $f’(x)$ must have at least one root.
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
  Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
  By \cref{thm:mvt}, there exists a number $c$ such that
  \begin{equation*}
    f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{0-0}{b-a} = 0.
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}
```

[image]

My questions are following:

1. Is this behavior typical for any proof environment containing math equations and adding the QED symbol at the end of it; or this another 'bug' in SIAM template file?
2. What is the correct way to type in proof environment math equations? 
   Previously I have used most often `\begin{equation*}\end{equation*}`, but here it produces the wrong behavior.

Comment: You should ***never*** use `$$` in LaTeX and this rules out one of your problems, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). Can you please show a minimal example of code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, never ever use `$$...$$` in LaTeX: you have discovered another reason why, but please have a look at [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Second, it's another feature of `ntheorem` with the `thmmarks` option, that modifies some environments but not all in order to provide automatic placement of the tombstone.

In particular `equation*` doesn't get redefined, so it's not in line with the automatic placement. You can make it compatible by redefining it.

```
\documentclass[
  %review
]{siamart0516}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% fix for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328946
\patchcmd{\SetTagPlusEndMark}{$}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SetTagPlusEndMark}{$}{}{}{}

% fix for the QED in equation*    
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\[}{\]\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{x} = x + y
\tag{$\bar{x}$}
\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\begin{corollary}
  Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere. If $f(x)$
  has at least two roots, then $f’(x)$ must have at least one root.
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
  Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
  By \cref{thm:mvt}, there exists a number $c$ such that
  \begin{displaymath}
    f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{0-0}{b-a} = 0.
  \end{displaymath}
\end{proof}

\begin{corollary}
  Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere. If $f(x)$
  has at least two roots, then $f’(x)$ must have at least one root.
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
  Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
  By \cref{thm:mvt}, there exists a number $c$ such that
  \begin{equation*}
    f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{0-0}{b-a} = 0.
  \end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\begin{corollary}
  Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere. If $f(x)$
  has at least two roots, then $f’(x)$ must have at least one root.
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
  Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
  By \cref{thm:mvt}, there exists a number $c$ such that
  \begin{equation}
    f’(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{0-0}{b-a} = 0.
  \end{equation}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

However, `equation` will not push the QED in the same position as `equation*` (I deem wrong the placement in `equation*`, but apparently this pleases the author of `ntheorem`).

[image]

Comment: I have found a slight misbehaviour if the `review` option of `siamart171218` is used. I fixed it with `\renewenvironment{equation*}{\[}{\]\ignorespacesafterend}`.

Comment: @gerw That's a very good suggestion