# ntheorem's fleqn and thmmarks options break \if@display

Tags: amsmath, inline, ntheorem, displaystyle

The following MCE points out `ntheorem`'s `fleqn` and `thmmarks` options break `\if@display`: e.g., as soon as `thmmarks` is uncommented, the 1st "equation" contains "Non-display math".

Do you see what's going on?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  amsmath,
  fleqn,
  % thmmarks
]{ntheorem}
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\testdisplaymath{%
  \if@display
  \text{Display math}
  \else
  \text{Non-display math}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\[
  \testdisplaymath
\]
$\testdisplaymath$
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Anyway, I discovered meanwhile that a better way to discriminate between display and non-display math would be to rely on `\mathchoice` and, as shown by the following MWE, this macro (unlike `\if@display`) isn't broken by `ntheorem`'s `fleqn` and `thmmarks` options:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  amsmath,
  fleqn,
  thmmarks
]{ntheorem}
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\testdisplaymath{%
  \mathchoice{%
    \text{Display math}%
  }{%
    \text{Non-display math}%
  }{%
    \text{Non-display math}%
  }{%
    \text{Non-display math}%
  }
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\[
  \testdisplaymath
\]
$\testdisplaymath$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another reason for not recommending this package.

Comment: This looks very much like a bug in the setup of the `thmmarks` option. Have you contacted the maintainer(s) of the `ntheorem` package and alerted them to this issue?

Comment: @Mico Maintainers informed about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you load the `thmmarks` option, `ntheorem` does

```
\gdef\[{%
  <code adding to the corresponding in the LaTeX kernel>
}
\gdef\]{%
  <code adding to the corresponding in the LaTeX kernel>
}
```

but `amsmath` had one

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

Since the LaTeX kernel code has no provision for `\if@display`, you get no support for it using `\[` and `\]`, unless you redo the latter declarations.
However, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329209/4427

Personal comment: the `thmmarks` option does so many changes in order to do something that simply requires `\qedhere` when needed and whose usage can be avoided by not ending a proof with a display or an enumerated list (of course with `amsthm` and not `ntheorem`).

Comment: When you say "However, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329209/4427", do you just mean "`thmmarks` is evil!" or am I missing something?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé That’s exactly what I think 

Comment: Unfortunately, redo the latter declarations leads to [extra vertical spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402387/18401).

Answer (score 0):

It's another problem with the compatibility of amsmath. amsmath compatibility is an issue since the early beginnings. Mails to amsmath people in the early stage of development (suggested by Frank Mittelbach at that time) were simply not answered by them.

Personally, I suggest not to use amsmath. This is also due to a bad experience with backwards version compatibility of amsmath.

Wolfgang (still partially active developer of ntheorem)

Comment: Seriously? `amsmath` and, based on it, `mathtools` provide so many, so nice features when one has to typeset maths that these packages are widely used nowadays.

Comment: Sorry, but a choice between `ntheorem` and `amsmath` is definitely for the latter.

Comment: amsmath is part of latex/required and any math document should include it. The only reason that it isn't included by default in the format is the memory constraints of emtex on a 540K PC.

Comment: So people using it should hope that they by now care for backward compatibility.

Comment: The responsibility for maintenance of amsmath was transferred to the latex team in 2016.

Comment: By the way, you may want to see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328973/4427