# Extra vertical spaces when \[ and \] are redefined as \begin{equation*} and \end{equation*} (ntheorem involved)

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath, ntheorem

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402194/18401), it is advised to proceed to the following redefinition:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

But, as pointed out by the following MCE, this leads to extra vertical spaces.

Do you see how to get rid of these extra spaces?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[step=1cm]{pagegrid}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,papersize=2.5cm]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,fleqn,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%
\newcommand{\test}{%
  \noindent%
  Foo
  \[
    a=a
  \]
  Bar
}
%
\begin{document}
\test
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}%
\newpage
\test
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I will remove my comments because I see only now your question is direct continuation of thread at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402187/ntheorems-fleqn-and-thmmarks-options-break-ifdisplay which already mentions thmmarks features...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align

Comment: No, the answer doesn't *recommend* to do that redefinition. It actually recommends not using `thmmarks`.

Comment: @egreg Okay, this answer gave that redefinition as a workaround, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance the spacing before and after is provided by `\topsep` (from a `trivlist`), whereas in the amsmath case it is `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`.  Setting the last two to `\topsep` gives the same spacing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[step=1cm]{pagegrid}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,papersize=2.5cm]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,fleqn,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%
\newcommand{\test}{%
  \noindent%
  Foo
  \[
    a=a
  \]
  Bar
}
%
\begin{document}
\test
%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\topsep}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\topsep}%
\newpage
\test
\end{document}
```