# Latex symbols not allowed in \tag{} Siam latex template

Tags: equations, journal, tags

I'm trying to get latex symbols in the label `\tag{}` for equations using the siam latex template.

Not sure why it's bringing up the error  `$\lambda$`  works in text just fine but if I use `\tag{$\lambda$}` it throws an error can anyone help?

```
\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart190516}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\headers{An Example Article}{D. Doe, P. T. Frank, and J. E. Smith}

\begin{document}
$\lambda$
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:beq}\tag{$lambda$}
  \sum_{v} a^C_v x_v \geq 1,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `siamart190516` is not a common class file, so I can't check any solution.  But it works fine if I `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: What is the error message that's being reported?

Comment: @Teepeemm  I don't find the code works and in fact I get an additional error of the form LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined  link to SIam latex template here https://www.siam.org/Information-for-Authors#LaTex2e-Standard

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Missing $ inserted

Comment: Not sure why, but `\tag{\ensuremath{\lambda}}` works.

Comment: This seems to be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328946.